# SQLite error : Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, ado.net

I am using `SQLite` in my Winforms application. I am copying `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` in output directory.

**App.config**

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" 
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

The application is throwing `"Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider"` error in some client's machines.

Please suggest me what should i do to fix this.

Comment: Please, could you tell us how you solved your issue please?

Answer (score 1):

**System.Data.SQLite.dll** completely depends on native library - 'sqlite3.dll'. So, you should install proper package on each machine, either x32 version or x64, and create two builds of the application - for x32 architecture and x64.

You can find more information about package types and its dependencies [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) in the *Package Types* section.